# Convert loop generating multiple Enumerables to single lazy Enumerable (or Enumerator?) in Ruby, possibly with flat_map/flatten

Tags: ruby, yield, enumerable, flatten

I'm using a gem that includes the following code, allowing one to call a block on each record returned by a web service query, even if that web service query is paged and requires multiple requests:

```
  def each(&block)
    yield_from_response &block
    while resumable?
      @response = @resumption_block.call @response
      yield_from_response &block
    end
  end

  private

  def yield_from_response(&block)
    @response.each do |obj|
      block.call(obj)
    end
  end

  def resumable?
    @response.resumption_token and not @response.resumption_token.empty?
  end
```

(For this question the details aren't very important, but for those who care, the gem is [ruby-oai](https://github.com/code4lib/ruby-oai) and the code in question is in [resumable.rb](https://github.com/code4lib/ruby-oai/blob/v0.3.1/lib/oai/client/resumable.rb).)

I'm trying to wrap `each()` here this in a method that returns an `Enumerable` of wrapper objects around each object in the response. If I don't care about resumption, I can avoid the above code and just access the response (which is an `Enumerable`) directly:

```
response ? response.map { |obj| MyGem::MyWrapper.new(obj) } : []
```

Now, it's easy enough for me to pass that block in:

```
response ? response.full.each { |obj| MyGem::MyWrapper.new(obj) } : []
# full() provides the resumable wrapper with each() and yield_from_response()
```

But in the resumption case, since `each` doesn't return anything useful, there's no way to get the results out.

The result set could be pretty large (larger-than-physical-RAM large), so I don't just want to dump everything into a temporary array, either explicitly or implicitly.

Clearly, what I need is to write my own alternative to `each()` that instead of taking a block, just returns an `Enumerable` of all the `objs` embedded in the `@responses`. I feel like there should be a simple way to do this without writing a complete `Enumerable` implementation, but I'm new enough to Ruby that it's not clear what it is.

The best I've been able to come up with is the following, which is also incorrect:

```
  def to_enumerable(response)
    response.each { |obj| yield MyGem::MyWrapper.new(obj) }
    resumption_block = response.resumption_block
    if resumption_block
      while response.resumption_token && !response.resumption_token.empty?
        response = resumption_block.call response
        response.each { |obj| yield MyGem::MyWrapper.new(obj) }
      end
    end
  end
```

It's incorrect because, of course, Ruby's `yield` doesn't really "yield", it just invokes a block, and if I wanted to pass in a block I could just call the original `each()`.

If I could figure out how to convert the repeated assignments to `response` into a sequence of `responses`, I could use `flat_map`, but I'm not sure how to do that.

---

**ETA:** On close inspection it looks like `Enumerable` isn't lazy, and if I want to avoid creating arrays (and thereby running out of memory for large datasets) I probably actually want `Enumerator`. If I understand the difference correctly.

Comment: If you don't want an array with the result what do you want to do with each individual result?

Comment: And `response.full.to_enum` is there already for you to have a Enumerator out of it

Comment: Okay, I see that `to_enum` works, but (1) where/how is it implemented, (2) what tells me that it's there, and (3) is it lazy?

Comment: At the moment, I personally want to run a block of code on each record, and so I'd be served well enough by `each`. But in the future, I (or other callers) might want to perform any of the `Enumerable` operations on the transformed collection.

Comment: ...though now, reading the documentation, it looks like nearly all the `Enumerable` methods create arrays, which is kind of useless for large data. Maybe I want `Enumerator` rather than `Enumerable`?